# How to make selection field with widget="priority" unhoverable or readonly in odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I want make the selection field with **widget="priority"** not hoverable or readonly. I applied **readonly="1"** but is not working on this widget. kindly help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

no problem in odoo 14
it could be a bug of priority wedget in odoo 11